# ASP.NET site. Redirect whole domain from http to https

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iirf

Just like in a title. How to redirect whole domain for example: **http://testdomain.com.au/** to **https://testdomain.com.au/** Can i do it in IIRF file ? If yes how this should look like ? How to bind IIRF file to site ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this via an `IIS Rewrite module`:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/redirect_http_to_https_iis_7

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Or you can redirect via the `Global.asax` file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( !Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
            string path = string.Format("https{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(4)); 

            Response.Redirect(path);
    }
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1340392.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. What about using IIRF file ? (Im asking just in case) ;)